Magento 2 How to modify admin dropdown attribute options
I have an admin dropdown attribute, which has a lot of options.

On admin product edit form, how can I show only the relevant options relative to the open product, for ease of admin user. I have a custom logic to filter out the relevant options for this attribute.
As the whole admin form is generated by ui component, it is difficult to find the origin.

Could you please provide more details about the options? For example, are you planning to handle them in the code or in a separate table? If it's a separate table, what columns do you plan to include?

@RajkumarVellaiswamy I am trying to handle it in code. As example, I want only the options which starts with a specific string.

Suppose you are managing a store that sells Books and Electronics. Each product type has its specific Format requirements:
Books:
Format options: Hardcover, Paperback, eBook.
Electronics:
Format options: Digital, Physical, Downloadable.

Instead of managing a single attribute with complex filtering logic, we can utilize attribute sets to group relevant attributes and automatically display them based on the selected attribute set.
Scenario 1: Adding a Book
Go to Catalog > Products > Add Product.
Select the Books attribute set.
The form shows the format_books dropdown with the options:

Hardcover
Paperback
eBook

Fill in the rest of the product details and save.
Scenario 2: Adding an Electronic Product
Go to Catalog > Products > Add Product.
Select the Electronics attribute set.
The form shows the format_electronics dropdown with the options:

Digital
Physical
Downloadable

Fill in the rest of the product details and save.
Using attribute sets in this way allows you to group and manage attributes for specific product types seamlessly. Each set has its dedicated attributes, and Magento's default behavior ensures that only the attributes relevant to the selected attribute set appear in the product form. This approach is clean, efficient, and avoids unnecessary complexity.
If this answer works as your expected, please mark it as accepted. That indicates your issue is solved and makes it easier for others with the same issue to find a verified answer. And that would be great if you click the upvote button for the answer in case you feel it is useful.
Happy Coding

Thank you, this is insightful. But unfortunately this won't work in my case.
